# What should be the output below Python code ? This code is from an online quiz and there its given answer is 0

Tags: python, function, recursion

This code is from an online quiz for Python.The answer on the website is given as 0. I don't understand the answer given in the quiz. As per my understanding, the answer should be (1,1).

```
def func(x, ans):
   if(x==0):
      return 0
   else: 
      return func(x-1, x+ans) 

print(func(2,0))
```

I expect the output of print (func(2,0)) to be (1,1), but the answer given is 0.

Comment: the answer is 0. Time for you to reason out the why. (ps, a good way to validate answers, just run it!)

Comment: `return 0` make `func` always return `0`.  
Also, this function cannot return `(1,1)`, its return type is number

Comment: Could you give out the reasoning why you think it returns (1,1)?

Comment: You probably missed the recursive func call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how some code works, a good practice is to just go through it line by line. So with this function that would be:

## What does this function do

First, the function checks whether its input `x` is equal to `0`. If it is, it returns `0` and by returning that also means that the function is finished.

```
if(x==0):
    return 0
```

If `x` is not equal to `0`, the if-statement will return `False`, resulting in the function to move on to the next lines:

```
else: 
    return func(x-1, x+ans)
```

Here the function calls itself with the `x` value decreased by `1`. So here we see that this function is actually a recursive function (More on recursive functions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and [here](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)). The second parameter of `func` is the `ans` value given to the original function added to the `x` value. This is the only occurrence of the `ans` variable, meaning that it actually has no meaning in the function itself.
Now by calling the function with the reduced `x` value, it will again check whether that value is equal to `0`. If it is it will return `0`, meaning that the `func` function that called this new `func` function will also return `0`. Or it will call the `func` function again with a reduced `x` value. It will do this until the `x` value becomes `0`.
This then means that the only value that will ever be returned from this function is `0`.

So, in short, the function will only be able to return `0`.

## Why not (1,1)

So, you think that the returned value of the `func` will be `(1,1)`. If you don't know what the function does, I do think I understand why you think this will happen. I guess that with these parameters in the return-statement of the function:

```
(x-1, x+ans)
```

`x` will be decreased by one, making it `1` (when the input is `(2, 0)`), because `2 - 1 = 1`. And using that `x` value in `x+ans`, makes `1 + 0 = 1`. Resulting in a returned value of `(1,1)`.

But like said, this is not true. The values are not calculated this way, they are just parameters given to the function so it can process them inside.
Also, like said, the function will only return `0`, which is an integer. This makes it impossible to return a tuple type like `(1,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Iteration 0: 
x = 2, ans = 0;
Goes to 'else' statement, now, x = 1, ans = 2.

Iteration 1:
x = 1, ans = 1;
Goes to 'else' statement, now, x = 0, ans = 3.

Iteration 2:
x = 0, ans = 3;
Goes to 'if' statement, returns from the function giving output '0'

Answer (score 0):

`return 0` make `func` always return `0`.
Also, this function cannot return `(1,1)`, its return type is number

---

How about below code?

```
def func(x, ans): 
    print(x, ans)
    if(x==0): 
        return ans # updated
    else: 
        return func(x-1, x+ans) 
print(func(2,0))
# output: 3
```

Or

```
def func(x, ans): 
    print(x, ans)
    if(x==0): 
        return 0
    else: 
        return (x-1, x+ans) #updated
print(func(2,0))
#Output: (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to track what is happening is by adding a couple of `print` statements in your function definition -

```
def func(x, ans):
     print(f"x is:\t {x}")
     print(f"ans is:\t {ans}")
     if(x==0):
         return 0
     else: 
         return func(x-1, x+ans)
```

And then run the function `print(func(2,0))` and see what values are printed out